# Ouput of Reversing words of String does not come as expected

Tags: java, string

> Given a String with words.Reverse words of String.

## Sample Input 1

Hello World

## Sample Output

World Hello

**MyApproach**

To reverse words I first counted how many spaces are there.After that I stored their space index in an array.Using lastIndex, I printed the last elements of the array.After that I printed the last 2 words of the array.

```
static String reverseWords(String inputString)
 {
    int l1=inputString.length();
    int count=1;
    for(int i=0;i<l1;i++)
    {
        char ch=inputString.charAt(i);
        if(ch==' ')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
     
    int k=0;
    int[] spaceindex=new int[count];
    spaceindex[0]=0;
    k++;
    for(int i=0;i<l1;i++)
    {
        char ch=inputString.charAt(i);
        if(ch==' ')
        {
            spaceindex[k++]=i+1;
        }
    }
    
    int p=spaceindex.length-1;
    String strnew="";
    for(int j=spaceindex[p];j<l1;j++)
    {
        char c=inputString.charAt(j);
        strnew=strnew+c;
    }
    

    p--;
    while(p>=0)
    {
         for(int j=spaceindex[p];;j++)
            {
             
              char c=inputString.charAt(j);
               if(c==' ')
               {
                   break;
               }
               strnew=strnew+c;
                
            }   
         
    }
   return strnew;   
}

InputParameters     ActualOutput                        Expected Output

Hello World         WorldHelloWorldHello(Infinite loop) WorldHello
```

@Edit I asked Why the code I wrote is wrong.I tried without using any inbuilt functions(which was necessary for me).In that way I think It is not Duplicate Ans according to me.

> Can anyone guide me what went wrong in my code.

Comment: You could use String.split to split on the space character, then just reverse the order of the array it gives you.

Comment: When you step through you code in your debugger what do you see?  Where do you change `p` inside your loop so it can stop?  Can you try using the formatter in your IDE so your code is easier to read?

Comment: @Berger I am guessing this is home work ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey oh yes, sorry :)

Comment: @Berger me too, whenever I answer a homework question without realizing it. ;)

Comment: You can also use `substring ` to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue within your code was the while loop:

```
 while(p>=0) {
        strnew = strnew + " ";
        for(int j=spaceindex[p];;j++) {
           char c=inputString.charAt(j);
           if(c==' '){
              break;
           }
           strnew=strnew+c;
        }   
        p--;
 }
```

Adding the `p--` will prevent the loop for occurring infinitely. Also inserting the `strnew = strnew + " ";` after the while loop ensures a space in between each word.

Comment: I think your Ans is perfect.Because you checked the code.+1 for that.Other Ans were correct obviously but They are for reference to make my hardcode a bit easy.Thank you for you work.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String x = "Hello World";
    String[] xArray = x.split(" ");
    String result = "";

    for (int i = xArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += xArray[i] + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(result.trim()); // World Hello
   }
```

Comment: You have an extra space here.

Comment: i don't understand , can you explain where is the extra space please ?

Comment: The last appended word shouldn't be followed by a space, so there is an extra space at the end of the result String.

Comment: add .trim() to the result to be : System.out.println(result.trim() );

Answer (score 1):

It's possible without using another arrays, splits or any additional strucure.

Having array of characters ( convert if needed as String is immutable), first reverse all characters in the array. Secondly loop over spaces and for each word reverse characters in the word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StringTokenizer to convert the string into tokens or String.split function. You can push this collection into a Stack and extract the elements in a reverse order. To join the strings back you could use a StringBuilder or a StringBuffer.

To do this more efficiently you could convert the string to a character array and StringBuilders

```
String myString = "Here is the String";
char[] myChars = myString.toCharArray();

StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = myChars.length - 1; --i >= 0;) {
   char c = myChars[i];
   if(c == ' ') {
       newString.append(c);
       newString.append(word);
       word = new StringBuilder();
   } else {
       word.append(c);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would base an implementation on [`String.lastIndexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-) and [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-). I'd got with a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to construct the output "sentence" and a [`while` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to iterate the words in reverse order. Something like,

```
static String reverseWords(String in) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(in.length());
    int space;
    while ((space = in.lastIndexOf(' ')) > 0) {
        sb.append(in.substring(space + 1, in.length())).append(' ');
        in = in.substring(0, space);
    }
    sb.append(in);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Which I tested with your provided sample

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverseWords("Hello World"));
}
```

Getting (as expected)

```
World Hello
```